# Yii2 REST choosing fields in extrafields

Tags: rest, yii2

From the yii2 definite guide:

```
public function fields()
{
    return ['id', 'email'];
}

public function extraFields()
{
    return ['profile'];
}
```

> the request with http://localhost/users?fields=id,email&expand=profile may return the following JSON data:

```
[
    {
        "id": 100,
        "email": "100@example.com",
        "profile": {
            "id": 100,
            "age": 30,
        }
    },
    ...
]
```

How can I tune extraFields (or maybe something else) to get only one field (for example, age) in profile section of response in this sample?

Answer (score 3):

This feature will be added in Yii 2.0.14
https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/pull/14219

Example API request will be work like this: `users?fields=id,email&expand=profile.age`

**Edit**: For now you can use something like this:

```
public function extraFields()
{
    return [
        'profileAge' => function($item){
            return $item->profile->age
        }
    ];
}
```

with request: `http://localhost/users?fields=id,email&expand=profileAge`

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)

Answer (score 1):

The first thing that came to mind

```
public function extraFields(){

    return [
        'profile' => function($item){
            return [
                'age' => $item->profile->age
            ];
        }
    ];
}
```

Comment: But what if I want to change them only for this model, cause I also want to see all fields when I request profiles directly.